# variable with multiple lines into one cell in excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a ps script with multiple "if" statements to output info if a checkbox is checked.  I have those IF statements assigned to a variable.  If I print out the variable (either on console or to a text file) the data is correct.  I need to be able to write the variable into a single cell in an excel spreadsheet.  I won't bore you with the entire script, but the important part.  Any help is appreciated.

```
function Build_table {
$global:Content =$(
if ($box1.checked -eq $true) {
write-output "box 1 is checked"
write-output "some other text here" }
if ($box2.checked -eq $true) {
write-output "Box 2 is checked" }
) }  #there are several more "if" statements, but they are all similar
```

I have the standard lines of code to open excel and select the correct worksheet which all work
fine.

```
$worksheet.Cells.Item(1,2) = "here is your list"
$worksheet.Cells.Item(2,2) = $Content
```

I have it populating other cells with other variables and that all works great since they are a single line of text.  But with `$Conent`, it does not put anything in the cell.

Sample data that is printed out when I print out `$Content`:

Box 1 is checked

Box 3 is checked

Box 3 some other text....

There are no spaces between the lines of data (I just don't know why it puts the double spacing in).

I need to be able to have that output inserted into the applicable cell in multiple lines as shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$content` is an **aray** of strings. To put that in a cell, you need it to become a single multiline **string**.

Try:

```
$worksheet.Cells.Item(2,2) = $Content -join [environment]::NewLine
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  I've been racking my brain for a couple days trying to find the answer.   Do you have a quick answer on how to make the cell autosize?  There could be over 20 lines of text that go in that cell